# Jquery - add some text to textbox and sort the textbox from Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I'm using ASP.NET asp:checkboxlist control with 36 listitems. which displays 36 checkboxes.
in HTML it displays  like below table. I also have a 
I would like to add the checked items in this div in sorted way. But when they uncheck the checkbox it should remove from the div. I display it , (comma separeted).

like:

selected :  5,6,9,12,25

I try to use Jquery. Below I try to add a click on the Checkboxes and I try to concat the values, but I'm struggling with the code. Can someone give some guide? at least what methods and how to sort in the div? It only contains numbers from 1-36.

```
    $(function () {
        var $tblChkBox = $("table.chk input:checkbox");
        $tblChkBox.click(function (e) {
            $('#chkBoxListNumbers').val($('#chkBoxListNumbers') +',');
        });
    });


<table id="chkBoxListNumbers" class="chk">
     <tr>       <td><input id="chkBoxListNumbers_0" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
       <td><input id="chkBoxListNumbers_1" type="checkbox" value="3"/></td>
       <td><input id="chkBoxListNumbers_2" type="checkbox" value="4"/></td>
       <td><input id="chkBoxListNumbers_3" type="checkbox" value="5"/></td>
     </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanations in comments:

```
$(function () {
    var $tblChkBox = $("table.chk input:checkbox");
    $tblChkBox.click(function (e) {
        checked = $("#chkBoxListNumbers input:checked"); // get all checked checkboxes in an array
        var ids = []; // prepare an array to store only the ID numbers
        checked.each( function () {
            ids.push(this.id.split("_")[1]); // iterate over the checked elements and push only the ID in
        });
        var joined = ids.join(","); // join them (equivilant to php's implode() )
        alert(joined); // alert the new string.. you can use this to put it in a div like $("#div_id").html(joined);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Rotem, this is exact what I want thank you... but my name of id is "MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel1History_chkBoxListNumbers_" ... So the "_" takes "Tabcontainer1" "Tabcontainer1, Tabcontainer1", "tabconatiner1, tabcontainer1,tabcontainer1" etc... Your solution is good, so accept your solution... could you just help me with these too? thanks again...

Comment: ok I got it I changed from [1] to [4] and it works great... super.. you're great.... thanks so much...

Answer (score 0):

nice @rotem-tamir could make this a little more condensed with:

```
ids.push(this.id.split("_"[4].join(",";
alert (joinded);
```